# Using Jackson 2.9.9 in java Spark

Tags: java, apache-spark, jackson, apache-spark-mllib

I am trying to use the MLLIB library (java) but one of my dependencies uses Jackson 2.9.9. I noticed that a pull request was made such that the master branch's dependency is upgraded to this particular version. Now I wanted to use this master branch so I cloned and installed this package using `./dev/make-distribution.sh`. but not sure which jar packages to copy to my project. I tried to copy all the 3.0.0-snaphots but I end up with a `class file for scala.Cloneable not found` in my java program.

I also did a `./build/mvn -DskipTests install` which installs the SNAPSHOT dependencies under ~/.m2.

I added them to the gradle build file

```
    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-core
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-core_2.12', version: '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'

    // https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.spark/spark-mllib
    compile group: 'org.apache.spark', name: 'spark-mllib_2.12', version: '3.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
```

but upon execution under java 11, it complains about:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9
    at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:207)
```

Since java 9 is not available anymore I am wondering how to further debug this issue. I assume at least java 9 is required but the field does no longer exists?

Answer (score 13):

I notice that in the sourcecode StorageUtils.scala, it is pulling in [apache common-lang3 for JAVA_9](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.9/index.html?org/apache/commons/lang3/JavaVersion.html). Have you check whether apache common-lang3 is included in the classpath? It solved my problem by adding commons-lang3-3.9.jar to my classpath.

Comment: This would have been better as a comment rather than an answer

Comment: why? @alee suggested some possible solution that might work.

Comment: Spark 3 requires `commons-lang3` >= 3.5. Adding this library (and making sure you get rid of older versions) fixed the problem for me when upgrading from Spark 2.