# spark submit error : Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9

Tags: java, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

this is the spark version i use,
`spark version 3.1.2` 
`hive version 3.1.2`

on my own project, i won't got this error , but after packaged the project , and do spark-submit , always got this error.

i have tried

1. add this in spark-submit`--conf spark.yarn.user.classpath.first="true"`
2. upload commons-lang 3.12.0 to `spark.yarn.jars`

still get this error ,has anyone ever encountered this problem

```
MemoryStore started with capacity 366.3 MiB
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: JAVA_9
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<init>(StorageUtils.scala:207)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.StorageUtils$.<clinit>(StorageUtils.scala)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.BlockManager.<init>(BlockManager.scala:213)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.create(SparkEnv.scala:394)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkEnv$.createExecutorEnv(SparkEnv.scala:205)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.$anonfun$run$7(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:4
42)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:62)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil$$anon$1.run(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
        at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1730)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkHadoopUtil.runAsSparkUser(SparkHadoopUtil.scala:61)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.run(CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:393)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend$.main(YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala:81)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.main(YarnCoarseGrainedExecutorBackend.scala)
```

Comment: access issue may be?

Comment: no , i use the right user to do spark submit.

Comment: Make sure you use Java 8, not Java 9 or above

Comment: While this is certainly a mismatch between a library used at runtime and one used at compile time, the cause is certainly that you have a version of commons-lang3 on your classpath that is too old, as mentioned in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57519804/using-jackson-2-9-9-in-java-spark). You should reexamine your classpath and remove any older versions of commons-lang3, and ensure that 3.5 or greater is present.